# Python: can't import dictionary from another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have problems importing a dictionary from an other file (I'm using python 2.7)

```
# src/config/config_bankheist.py
bankheist_config = {

    ###############################
    # SECTION 1 : ENTERY OF HEIST #
    ###############################
    'activation_command': '!bankheist',

    (...) # More key/values here

} # End of bankheist_config
```

And when I try to import it in the main file where it's used:

```
#src/lib/commands/bankheist.py
import string

from src.lib.timers import InfiniteTimer
import src.lib.irc as irc_

from src.config.config import config
from src.config.config_bankheist import bankheist_config as bankheist

def check_init_status():
    try:
        return bankheist['init_status']
    except KeyError:
        bankheist['init_status'] = False
        return False
```

So here i try to return the value by the key 'init_status'. The first time, it won't find the key, as bankheist isn't initiated yet... So normaly I would ket a KeyError not found. Instead, I get a *TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__ getitem __'*.

I tried adding the init_status key to the dictionary and initialize it on False, I even tried to import is as a global variable (say that it's global on the config file, and global on the define methode), I tried to put the bankhiest_config as bankhiest in the same file, and it stil don't works..

I have something similar with config_command.py (same folder as config_bankheist.py) and commands.py (same folder as bankheist.py) and that works.. So I'm not sure what I am doiing wrong here.

Thanks in advance,
Laurens

PS: if interested, full code is on github: https://github.com/LaurensScheldeman/TwitchBot/commits/master

Comment: are you sure you don't have another object (from traceback a function) named `bankheist` inside of your `bankheist` module?

Comment: `__init__.py` missing in src/config ?

Comment: __init__.py in all directories, not the issue @Chintan and the file itself is called bankheist.py... could that be the problem? As i'm importing that file: module = importlib.import_module('src.lib.commands.%s' % command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have function object named [`bankheist`](https://github.com/LaurensScheldeman/TwitchBot/blob/master/src/lib/commands/bankheist.py#L10-L50), so your imported `dict` object is overwritten after `bankheist` function definition

try to leave initial `dict` object name `bankheist_config`

```
import string

from src.lib.timers import InfiniteTimer
import src.lib.irc as irc_

from src.config.config import config
from src.config.config_bankheist import bankheist_config

def check_init_status():
    try:
        return bankheist_config['init_status']
    except KeyError:
        bankheist_config['init_status'] = False
        return False
```

Comment: @Laurens: you are welcome, as a bonus: give distinct names to different objects, because it makes code easier to read (especially for authors of code since they are main readers)